# Is there a way to change the title of one of Eclipse's default views, programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plug-in that uses Eclipse's 'Problems' view and I would really like to change the title to `Errors'.

Is there any way for me to change this programmatically or can I extend the problems view without having to create my own custom marker view?

I know that to change a view title you use setParName in the viewPart class but since I am using one of Eclipse's views, I don't have the viewPart class.

Comment: That view is used by your plugin and _many_ other plugins in the same Eclipse installation, therefore you should be a good citizen and not modify such a central piece. This might be OK for an RCP application, but I consider this quite a design failure for a normal plugin integrating into the IDE.

Comment: Yes I agree. The accepted answer does not affect the actual view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom perspective, you can set a name for the view if you add it in the plugin.xml ("Extensions" tab of the manifest) instead of the custom perspective class.

nEm: I just wanted to add that to make sure you choose this class if you want the error marker behaviour

```
org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ProblemsView
```

Since there is also another Problem view.

Comment: So you mean then do something like view.SetPartName("Errors")?

Comment: I get a discouraged access warning when I import the ProblemsView and there is no setPartName or setTitle. There is only a setPartProperty(String key, String value). Also, I put this in my custom Perspective class after I add the problems view to it.

Comment: If you have a custom perspective, can't you set a name for the view if you add it in the plugin.xml ("Extensions" tab of the manifest) instead of the custom perspective class?

Comment: Ah yes that works! Is there anyway for me to also keep the same icon as the problems view? As there is no icon for it anymore.
Also can you edit your answer to this solution so I can accept it or I can edit it, if that's ok.

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Maybe you have to copy that icon from the eclipse folder to a folder in your project and reference that. Try to search the eclipse folder for .gif-images

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking but they are all in different folders with numbers as their names... so it will take me a while to find it! But anyways the title was the main issue. Thanks for updating the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own view definition that works very similar to the ProblemsView by creating a customized Markers view.

`org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ProblemsView` uses the markers generator  *org.eclipse.ui.ide.problemsGenerator*.  Once you create a class that subclasses `org.eclipse.ui.views.markers.MarkerSupportView` and provides the marker generator, you can use a simple view definition:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
   <view class="com.example.MyErrorView"
         icon="icons/sample.gif"
         id="com.example.myErrorView"
         name="My Error View"/>
</extension>
```

See http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/11/creating-custom-marker-view.html by Prakash for a more complex example.  Using the icon from another plugin is tricky, because there's no guarantee that it remains where it is, but if you really want to you can use

```
icon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.ide/icons/full/eview16/problems_view.gif"
```

Just a note, the above format doesn't support changing the NL of the icon.

Comment: Yes this is also a good idea. I just wanted to avoid creating a custom view as I want everything exactly how it is in the Problems view, just with the title changed.